# Inverted Carthage script on M1

Tags: ios, apple-m1, carthage

I had trouble doing a carthage bootstrap on M1 machine without using xcframeworks.
I have read that the best way to use Carthage on M1 chip is by running it with --use-xcframworks option.

Problem is, we had lots of our own .frameworks that also dependent on .frameworks that we list in the main app.
For example: // "->" meaning "depends on"

- Main App -> RxSwift
- Main App -> PrivateUIFramework -> RxSwift

and we have more than 50 framework, so it's going to be a hassle if i start converting everything to .xcframeworks.

So i was wondering could i applied the opposite of what @rastersize's Script do? so instead removing arm64 from iphone-simulator, i want to remove arm64 from iOS build
so i could run my project on M1